# Prove that n is a multiple of $16$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $n\ge2$ be a natural number and $A,B$ two real matrices of dimension $5$ so that $A^2+B^2=\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{2}}AB$ and $\det(AB-BA)>0$. Prove that $n$ is a multiple of $16$.

I don't know how to solve it. I just know that the trace of $AB-BA$ is $0$ and also then, from Cayley-Hamilton, I have that $(AB-BA)^2<0$ which is false; from here I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Questions of this kind have been asked before. For example, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240983) and the various solution tricks illustrated in its answers. The following is my attempt using one of those tricks.

Let $c=\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{2}}$ and let $z$ be a complex root to the equation $z+\frac{1}{z}=c$. Let $X=A-zB$ and $Y=A-\frac{1}{z}B$. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z}XY-zYX
&=\frac{1}{z}(A-zB)\left(A-\frac{1}{z}B\right)-z\left(A-\frac{1}{z}B\right)(A-zB)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{z}-z\right)A^2-\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-z^2\right)AB+\left(\frac{1}{z}-z\right)B^2\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{z}-z\right)\left[A^2-\left(\frac{1}{z}+z\right)AB+B^2\right]\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{z}-z\right)\left(A^2-cAB+B^2\right)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Therefore $XY=z^2YX$. As $0<\det(XY-YX)=\det((1-z^2)YX)$, both $X$ and $Y$ are nonsingular. Take determinants on both sides of $XY=z^2YX$, we get $z^{10}=1$. Since $z+\frac{1}{z}=c$, the scalar $z$ is a $10$-th root of unity that satisfies the equation $\left[\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^n-2\right]^n=2$, i.e., $\left[(z^2+1)^n-2z^n\right]^n=2z^{n^2}$. Now I have forgotten most of what I learned from university and do not know how to continue from here.

(I always visit this site using the Tor Browser. Probably due to a code change on this site, I am told by this site that "Editing is currently forbidden". I cannot edit my answer to fix any possible error and I cannot respond to comments. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.)