# $AB-BA$ invertible and $A^2+B^2 = AB$ then $3$ divides $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $AB-BA$ invertible and $A^2+B^2 = AB$ then prove that : $3 \mid n$.

I tried to manipulate or find some factorisation in order to be able to use efficiently eigenvalues...  but I dind't find anything.

Thank you !

Comment: Related questions when $A$ and $B$ are complex (and not necessarily real): (1) [Prove that MN-NM is Singular](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3018294), (2) [$A^2+B^2=AB$ and $BA-AB$ is non-singular](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1768707).

Comment: See also: [Square matrices satisfying certain relations must have dimension divisible by $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299651).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an addendum to Sqyuli's answer that (hopefully) explains some of the motivation behind the solution. It's too long to phrase in a comment, so I'll add a bit of the sketch of that answer here (in slightly different notation)

1. Set $\omega$ be a primitive third root of unity (note that $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$).
2. Let $A+\omega B=M$, and consider $M\overline{M}$.
3. Show that $\det(M\overline{M})$ is real.
4. Use the second condition to reduce this to $\omega(BA-AB)$, and see

$$\det(\omega(BA-AB))=\omega^n\det(BA-AB)\in\mathbb{R}.$$

5. Conclude that $3\mid n$.

The key motivating step is to notice the factorization

$$a^2+ab+b^2=(a+\omega b)\left(a+\frac{1}{\omega} b\right),$$

which one can notice for example by noting $\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}=a^2+ab+b^2$. Unfortunately, this isn't applicable directly, as for one we **certainly** can't say that $A$ and $B$ commute (which would allow us to factor the second condition but invalidate the first). However, it does indicate somehow that $A\pm\omega B$ could be useful, and $A\pm\frac{1}{\omega}B$ as well via multiplication of the two. We attempt this, and see (remembering that $A$ and $B$ do not commute) that

\begin{align*}
(A+\omega B)\left(A+\frac{1}{\omega} B\right)
&=A^2+B^2+\omega(BA)+\frac{1}{\omega}(AB)\\
&=AB\left(1+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)+\omega(BA)\\
&=\omega(BA)-\omega(AB)\\
&=\omega(BA-AB),
\end{align*}

from which the importance of the first condition becomes apparent.

Comment: The 4th step (+using a primitive 3rd root of unity) and your key factorization are really the main parts. Playing around with that and ;) Thanks Carl for this motivation!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I don't think I would have found that...

Answer (score 6):

This problem is an old problem of the IMC from 1997. You can find a solution of your question on their [website](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahjej/imc/imc1997/problems.html).

The following is your problem divided in small parts, if you would like to try it by yourself (what I would suggest.)

1. Let $z = -\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \in \mathbb{C}$ and define $M \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as $M = A+zB$
2. Show that $\det(M\overline{M}) \in \mathbb{R}$.  [Hint: $z\overline{z} \in \mathbb{R}$]
3. Write $M\overline{M}$ as $z \cdot (...)$ and observe $\det(M\overline{M})=z^n\cdot \det(...)$. Also show that $\det(...) \neq 0$
4. Combine 2. and 3. to show that $3\mid n$.

Personally I don't know how anyone found $z$ and $M$ as defined above by solving this exercise. Perhaps someone else could explain this. In other words: I see that it works with $z$ and $M$ as defined above and I also understand the idea of the proof, but the definition of $z$ and $M$ appear out of nowhere (for me).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's a nasty trick but it's definitely really hard to find. I am wondering if some contestants found this during the competition.