# $AB-BA$ invertible and $A^2+B^2 = AB$ i.f.f $3 \mid n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

> Let $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $AB-BA$ invertible and $A^2+B^2 = AB$ then prove that : $3 \mid n$.

I have seen answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109173/ab-ba-invertible-and-a2b2-ab-then-3-divides-n?noredirect=1&lq=1). But I was wondering if the other direction is also true, that is: say we have $A^2+B^2 = AB$ and if $3 \mid n$, then $AB-BA$ is invertible. If it is not true, then are there any cases divided where if A and B are nonzero, then AB-BA is either invertible or not invertible?

Comment: I can't figure out what your edited question even means.  I'm tempted to say "yes, every matrix is either invertible or not invertible, including $AB-BA$"

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider e.g. $A=B=$ any nonzero nilpotent matrix whose square is zero.

For a less obvious counterexample, let
$$
C=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&1},
\ X=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0},
\ Y=\pmatrix{0&0&\frac12\\ -1&0&0\\ 0&2&0}.
$$
It can be verified that $C^2+I=C$ and $X^2+Y^2=XY$. For every $n$ that is $\ge6$ and divisible by $3$, put
\begin{cases}
A= C\oplus\cdots\oplus C\ \text{ and }\ B=I&\text{ when $n$ is even},\\
A= C\oplus\cdots\oplus C\oplus X\ \text{ and }\ B=I_{n-3}\oplus Y&\text{ when $n$ is odd}.\\
\end{cases}
Then $A$ and $B$ are invertible, $A^2+B^2=AB$ but $AB-BA$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

In any dimension, $A=B=0$ provides an immediate counterexample.

Comment: what about dimension divisible by3 in general?

Comment: What I wrote is true in any dimension in fact.

Comment: sorry, let me clarify, are there any obvious cases where if A and B are nonzero, then AB-BA is either invertible or not invertible?

Comment: @jamesblack Please update your question with the appropriate details... to avoid a moving question which is not easy to answer.

Comment: sorry its updated, thanks